# hector_slam under ROS electric

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Has anyone tried to run hector_slam under ROS electric?
I got the error like below all the time..
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied

Does anybody have an idea about that?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11405/hector_slam-under-ros-electric/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This most likely hasn't got anything to do with hector_slam but with the permissions you have set for the checked out svn directory. Are you sure that the user you're logged in with has the necessary permissions to create directories there?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on 2011-10-05**:
Yes you are right! I got it now.